# What suitable Q & A application can integrate with a Java portal?

Tags: applications, workflows

I'm looking for suggestions on whether **we should build** *or* **are there readymade applications** that do the following:

- Allow admins to build a structured
  workflow of support Q & A, similar to
  Windows Troubleshooting i.e. when you
  try one tip, you then get the next
  one.
- Allow end-users to search and follow
  the Q & A

We have an existing Liferay portal which we would like to plug in this app to it - is there some suitable app like a CMS which does this? I mean building the structured questions - not just plain content like a wiki.

Open source options are welcome, but I'd like to know of COTS as well.

Comment: By a Q & A application, you mean that the CMS supports a survey feature (irrespective of whether it is supported intrinsically or as an add-on)?

Answer (score 1):

[Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview) is a pretty good solution. We use it where I work for knowledge management. It is primarily a wiki, but extremely extensible with good integration with Office, JIRA, etc. You can definitely create content flows for end users similar to what you're seeking. Not sure about Liferay integration, although I just heard we're moving our enterprise portal to Liferay this year, so hopefully it's not to much of a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

use Wordpress. Wordpress will have a core simple cms and you can extend it using its plugins.   It can be easily integrated with any kind of site.  To do those You need a good wordpress programmer.

Answer (score 0):

[Moodle](http://moodle.org/development/) is a free CMS that has several survey-like modules. It's in PHP so it could run on a Java platform or even embed a portal within the php pages:

> a Course Management System (CMS), also known as a Learning Management
>   System (LMS) or a Virtual Learning Environment (VLE). It is a Free web
>   application that educators can use to create effective online learning
>   sites.